# sort doubles stored as strings ?

Tags: java, string, sorting

Hi is there any way to parse strings into numbers? And is there any way to check if a string is a number or not without breaking the program ? I am thinking about using a try and catch would this be a good idea ?

Comment: how do I do it without crashing the program?

Comment: @Ingo, you answered the questions in the cleanest way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way to check if a string is parseable or not without trying to parse the string (as any check would have to start trying to interpret the string as a number to do that...). For a half-way check, I guess you could use Regex to check if the string has only digits and periods. You'll have to use a try... catch block aswell, though.

As to how to parse a string into a double, try this:

```
double dd;
try {
    dd = Double.parseDouble(string);
}
catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    System.out.println("couldnt not parse the string!");
}
```

Comment: It's not good to rely on exception handling in a *"non-exceptional circumstances"*...

Comment: @dacwe agreed, but the way the library works doesn't really give you any option here.

Comment: You can always implement the same check that check that the API does (http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 3):

Yes. [Double.valueOf(String s)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29) will throw a `NumberFormatException` if your string can't be parsed to a Double and return the parsed Double otherwise.

Comment: and it would crash. But how would I set up to catch and try because my file has strings that I am storing also. I just want to know if a string is in the string column and number is in the number column

Comment: @chuck http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to sort using one of the assorted built-in sort methods. In that case, you'll need to create a custom `Comparator<T>`, implementing `compare()` and `equals()` that attempts to parse the strings as `Double`, and on catching an exception, implements some sane default behavior. Make sure to catch the exception within your methods - you should only run into problems if you let the exceptions get out into the Java API code.

As a quick example to get you going:

```
class DoubleStringComparator implements Comparator<String> {

    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        try {
            double d1 = Double.parse(o1);
            double d2 = Double.parse(d2);
            if d1 > d2 {
                return 1;
            } else if d1 < d2 {
                return -1;
            else {
                return 0;
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // whatever ordering you want to impose when one string is not a double
        }
    }

    // some definition of equals() - whatever makes sense for your application

}
```

Then, when you want to do the sorting:

```
Collections.sort(someListOfString, new DoubleStringComparator());
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at parseDouble

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29

and yes you can catch NumberFormatException to determine when the number wasn't valid.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to find if the strings  is double or not

```
if(num1.matches(("((-|\\+)?[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?)+"))){
    isDoubleVal =true;                  
}else{
    isDoubleVal = false;
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Regards,
Lav

Comment: That doesn't cover double strings like `"1.9E42"`